# Discord Python Rewrite - Cogs Error (client.load_extention(cog) AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'load_extention')

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I tried to use Cogs in Discord.Py Rewrite, and I got this error message:

> ```
> "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Code\Project 01\index.py", line 410, in <module>
>
>     File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Code\Project 01\index.py", line 407, in <module>
>     client.load_extention(cog) AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'load_extention' [Finished in 1.6s with exit code 1]
>
> [shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Code\Project 01\index.py"]
> [dir: C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Code\Project 01] [path: C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA
> Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program
> Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\;C:\ffmpeg\bin;C:\Users\PC\Desktop\heroku\bin;C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Microsoft
> VS Code\bin]
> ```

My cog (admin.py):

```py
import discord from discord.ext import commands
     
class Admin(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
     
    @commands.command(aliases=["announce"])
    async def say1(self, ctx, *, text):
        ctx.send(text)
        return print("Cog Loaded")

def setup(client): 
   client.add_cog(Admin(client))
```

My main code (index.py):

```py
for cog in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if cog.endswith(".py"):
        try:
            cog = f"cogs.{cog.replace('.py', '')}"
            client.load_extention(cog)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"{cog} Can not be loaded")
            raise e
```

Can anyone help? I need to use Cogs too. (My Python Version is 3.8.5 and my Discord.Python Version is the latest one)

Comment: It's not `load_extention` but `load_extension` you made a typo.
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.load_extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misstyped something, it should be extension not extention

```
for cog in os.listdir("./cogs"):
if cog.endswith(".py"):
    try:
        cog = f"cogs.{cog.replace('.py', '')}"
        client.load_extension(cog)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{cog} Can not be loaded")
        raise e
```